# Make map with legend fit to the container which changes size on resizing the window

Tags: d3.js

This is my current code which has all the parameters predefined(i.e having fixed size)

**Code+Demo:**

https://plnkr.co/edit/AzflYyovnJ6YwE5I?preview

But the thing is the container will be responsive I want (map+legend) to be fit inside it. (map+legend) should be able to adjust themselves wrt to the container.

**some part of my code from the current code:**

```
var map = d3.select("#chart")

const width = w;//map1.node().getBoundingClientRect().width;
const height = h;//width / 2;

const zoom = d3.zoom()
.scaleExtent([1, 40])
// .translateExtent([[0,0], [width, height]])
.extent([[0, 0], [width, height]])
.on("zoom", zoomed);

const svg = map.append("svg:svg")
.attr("width", width)
.attr("height", height)
.call(zoom);

const india = svg.append("g").attr("id", "india");
```

I tried few of the things from the solutions I got on the net. But It didn't work out for me.

This is my **failed attempt**: https://plnkr.co/edit/KKiTe9exaBW8B9gP

### Edit:

Finally able to do it but there is something wrong. On resizing, my map disappears.

http://plnkr.co/edit/MjynaqFnE7qpad6G?preview

## Edit2:

Finally found the error:
This code from `SizeChange` function is the root of all.
I need to transform in such a that it will be in the center I don't know how to do it?

```
d3.select("g").attr("transform", "scale("+$("#chart").width() + $("#chart").height() + ")");
```

Comment: Can you share the way that you've structured your chart containers? (e.g., body > div container for 6 charts > individual chart container div for each chart > svg ) If you share the HTML structure for the doc we'll be able to help out in the clearest way.

Comment: @scrollex: Can you see the edit? I am able to do it now but my graph gets vanished.